# Why can't Typescript detect that an object is defined when using && short-circuit evaluation of multiple levels of keys in the object?

Tags: typescript

Why is the code below problematic, I am testing that an object which has multiple nested keys, is in fact not undefined at each level before I test the next, yet TS says that the object is possibly undefined.

The relevant test is:

```
chartAnnotations[ts] && chartAnnotations[ts][side] && chartAnnotations[ts][side][type]
```

```
interface Transaction {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number
}

type ChartTransaction = Pick<Transaction, 'prop2'>

export type Order = {
  status: string;
  type: string;
}
export interface ChartExecutionData {
  submitted?: Order[];
  open?: Order[];
  executed?: Order[];
  canceled?: Order[];
  partiallyExecuted?: Order[];
  transaction?: ChartTransaction;
}
type AnnotationObjectByType = { [type in keyof ChartExecutionData]: string };

interface ChartAnnotationsBySide {
  buy?: AnnotationObjectByType;
  sell?: AnnotationObjectByType;
}

interface ChartAnnotations {
  [timestamp: number]: ChartAnnotationsBySide;
}

const chartAnnotations: ChartAnnotations = {}

type SidesArr = Array<keyof ChartAnnotationsBySide>

const sides: SidesArr = ['buy', 'sell']

type TypesArr = Array<keyof ChartExecutionData>

const types: TypesArr = ['submitted']

const ts: number = 433242
sides.forEach(side => {
  types.forEach(type => {
    if (chartAnnotations[ts] && chartAnnotations[ts][side] && chartAnnotations[ts][side][type]) {

    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Did you mean `chartAnnotations[ts] && chartAnnotations[ts][type] && chartAnnotations[ts][type][status]`

Comment: I've updated to what i mean. sorry for the mistake.

Comment: It still seems the second part of the short-circuit is testing the same as the first and you mean to go one level deeper?

Comment: chartAnnotations[ts] && chartAnnotations[ts][side] && chartAnnotations[ts][side][type]

Comment: In the last element of that test, it says that chartAnnotaions[ts][side] is possibly undefined. But didn't I just test that in the previous element of the &&

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in TypeScript.  For whatever reason, reading a non-literal property on an object type with an index signature doesn't act as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types) on that property.  It looks like this is being tracked in the following GitHub issues:

- [microsoft/TypeScript#17960](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17960) "property accesses on string index signatures should narrow"
- [microsoft/TypeScript#29042](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29042) "`this[variable]` and `this[stringLiteral]` have different behavior"

You might want to go to those issues and give them a  if you want to see them maybe come out of the backlog.

In the meantime, workarounds:

---

You could save the result of the property access to a new variable, and then check it.  This should trigger the type guarding you expect.  For example:

```
let cAts: AnnotationObjectByType | undefined;
if (chartAnnotations[ts] && (cAts = chartAnnotations[ts][side]) && cAts[type]) {

}
```

---

Or, if you're using TypeScript 3.7+ (currently in beta) you can use the [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33294), which will most likely [eventually be added to JavaScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining).  This is a less verbose syntax to do the kind of safe nested indexing you want, and luckily it doesn't run afoul of the same bug:

```
const cAtst = chartAnnotations?.[ts]?.[side]?.[type]; // string | undefined
```

---

Or, if you just want to silence the error and go about your day, you can use the [non-null assertion operator `!`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

```
if (chartAnnotations[ts] && chartAnnotations[ts][side] && chartAnnotations[ts][side]![type]) { }
```

This is less safe than the previous two workarounds, but changes your code the least.

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ts=3.7-Beta&ssl=54&ssc=1&pln=55&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpTiAzoswD2IyA3gLABQyyADlPtQIwBcyWYUoA5gNwVW30ATCxABXALYAjaBQC+FCmACe1FAGEAFnChh0mHAjyFkAXmQAFYAgDWAHj3ZcBEABpkAcgHVB7gHwLyCAAPanwdZGVVZAB5KAATaFMSPlYwODBRLBY2DhAeFMiIbPYuXnJ5QJCwsGRQSFhEdS0dAFEgiARRIxAAEXS4ZMpWUUlxYDBIOIB+FliEqABtAF0yqnoIEBmY+Ohl1eRgjq6IadmdxZWUhEwkABsTrbndy6HqbTw4W9ulNqPJx-OewKGEchmcW007wcBm6ZQqhWQAEEQCB8GlutFJAArDpgABCSlQKhQZmIyAWCNAyGsECU+BgyEhrXanW6fTSS2KuU4yFkZQodWg8CQjOaYGRqPRziwBIAysAEoMqJJREothK0elnJicYYCUTVPssBAvuqUZqMdjcfriXCAoKGiKmeLzVLCFgleS8OIIGw4OJqCIJNIoJzRe8NW7sHKFRA7eQKAh3TUEGLI1r3Sxnenuh7SRVFMTkPKElhEVAoElyxglLYaXSGdnXRno0oSxB-AnyEnsDUsLGssWB9Wkgt3CqlO43O5jV93EsAgiDb6R2Zq3Ba-X6eHmX9nOy4J3E8mIsTB8uyxXRzORmMJid5wFj72IoOxFJEmYACwAZh-gi-QQKH7UsADoYDCFpEA0AAKECSV8T1CiwcDIOgmCERMRCyC7KgqAAenw5AQAgAB3ZAADdtGAOBJHuFIqHuFNETAQcc21K09UJIsAB9kFEEAEhgUATn2KhgAZGDUwjZtcwpLAlmQAAyJTkCkli82QaSdHY915KWBZ4KWABKZTVIQDSKWJEySF5AI8OQQjkHobpPi0rRQC4ZAplAhitJPCzWJqMxtJdSUWywHz9KioyosKFZHKInIvL4gShJEuJ7LwpzURAABaMQvmQOAsGNHRnGQABCPyJLU0LdOwfSzPcmTwrk1iDKM5r6tk6V9MM2MlkqqzVBsskCyGWRjLkYygA)

Answer (score 1):

I've created [a small example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=41&pc=1#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) that may show why this doesn't work.

I'm not 100% sure, but I think it is because TypeScript won't know at compile time what property you're trying to access with the key variable is, so it can't be certain that that value is not undefined.

**Edit:** To add a solution to this answer as well, checking if a property exists will work *in JavaScript* so to make TypeScript not complain, you can use [a type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) and tell TS that you know for sure it won't be undefined wherever you need it.